# Python Scrapy - How can I reset/clear memory of visited urls for scrapy "dont_filter=False"?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a website that have the same urls when I am searching for different things. I need my spider to have `dont_filter=False` on several methods to not duplicate items while I am browsing through pagination. But with next search I would to reset or rather clear "memory" of visited urls.

I am wondering If I need to create some unique list myself to keep track of visited urls and the purge them when I would like or there is some built in function alongside `dont_filter=False` ?

Thanks and Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I’m missing some data to make a proper suggestion (why do you need identical requests while browsing? are they really identical?), but most solutions would go through implementing your own [duplicate filtering class](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class).

For example, you could make the duplicate filter take into account a custom meta key, and assign that meta key a different value depending on the type of request (e.g. `browse` or `search`), so that the filtering of one type of request does not affect the filtering of the other type of request.